# [Java Swing AWT]: why is this exception raised out of my code?

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt

In our Java RMI distributed board game (where player are seen as a virtual ring network where one player allows the following to play his turn as soon as it has finished his) sometimes a client cannot initialize its GUI because the one sending it the permission to do it raises and exception. The exception is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 91
at java.awt.Container.getComponent(Container.java:327)
at javax.swing.JComponent.rectangleIsObscured(JComponent.java:4391)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1052)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and so the client freezes at the login window and it cannot play. Sometimes this happens, sometimes it does not. We don't know why because as you can see there is any reference to our code at which the exception has raised...we jave only understood that it is a problem with swing/awt...do you know anything?

Comment: If ever you feel the need to ask "Is it a bug in [framework being used by literally millions of other programs]", the answer is almost always "NO!".

Comment: I don't think it's a bug...I know I am making a mistake somewhere but as the exception stack trace is not saying where, then it's hard for me to understand...

Comment: Since the exception is "ArrayIndexOutofBounds" in a getComponent, the first thing I'd look to see is if you've added something invalid to one of your Managers or Containers.

Answer (score 2):

Normally such errors only occurs if GUI operations are performed outside of the AWT/Swing Event Dispatch Thread. It seems that an other Thread is changing your GUI while Swing tries to repaint the View.

You can try http://www.swingexplorer.com/ to find EDT Violations, but the program is not always reliable.

Comment: I will have a trial with that program. In all the project we've always used Swing.invokeAndWait() to bu sure that the core program executed only after when GUI updates were finished...so, i'm really surprised. Thank you.